# Rails strong parameters of enumerated type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got paramerers which are sent by a form like:

```
{ "mac"=>{"0"=>["111", "222"], "1"=>["333", "444"]} }
```

How can I permit them in a proper way, because I've found just an ugly solution:

```
params.permit(mac: Hash[(0..100).map { |i| [i.to_s, []] }])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the keys out of the `:mac` key and then permit them.

```
mac_keys = params.fetch(:mac, {}).keys
params.permit(mac: mac_keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

will you consider the hash's keep_if method, as params is just a hash.

```
params[:mac].keep_if {|k, v| k.to_i >= 0 and k.to_i <= 100}
```